# Dart how to access second dimension in multidimensional map

Tags: flutter, dart

I can manage to access the first dimension with `mymap['status']` but I tried to access the second dimension with `mymap['status'].start` or `mymap['status']['start']` but neither work.

Also I don't see why `mymap.status` doesn't work for the first dimension?

```
const mymap = {
  'status': {
    'start': ['Start', 'ok', 'go'],
  },
  'update': {
    'now': ['Start', 'ok', 'go'],
  },
  'time': [
    ['20', '10s', '5s'],
         ['45', '30s', '15s']
  ]
};
```

Also not sure whether this map should have the data type `Map` or not but with it I get no error signal with `mymap['status'].start` but upon executing the code it throws the error `Class '_ImmutableMap<String, List<String>>' has no instance getter 'start'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix your issue use a static type `Map` after `const` , like this :

```
const Map mymap = {
  'status': {
    'start': ['Start', 'ok', 'go'],
  },
  'update': {
    'now': ['Start', 'ok', 'go'],
  },
  'time': [
    ['20', '10s', '5s'],
         ['45', '30s', '15s']
  ]
};

 print(mymap['status']['start']);
```

You can run the code if you want https://dartpad.dartlang.org/20eab4288fbf688c6517365b89fc2b22

Answer (score 1):

You look up values for keys in a Dart `Map` using `map[key]`. If the key is a string, that would be `mymap["status"]`. You cannot use `mymap.status` because map keys are completely separate from class members. That's why you can do both `map["length"]` and `map.length` and get different results.

In your example, the *static type* of `mymap` is inferred to be `Map<String, Object>`.
This is inferred because the *values* of your map are either `Map<String, List<String>>` (for `"status"` and `"update"`) or `List<List<String>>` (for `"time"`). The only common supertype of `Map` and `List` is `Object`, so your map is a `Map<String, Object>`.

When you then write `mymap['status']` you get an expression with static type `Object`, and you are not allowed to do `['start']` on that (`Object` does not have an `[]` operator).

If you type your variable as `Map<String, dynamic>`, then you are allowed to do `mymap['status']['start']`. The final index operation is a *dynamic* invocation, which comes at some run-time cost.

Alternatively, you can do `(mymap['status'] as Map<String, List<String>>)['start']` which casts the looked-up value to a map of the correct type, and then does a well-typed lookup on the that map.