# dart/flutter print single value from map

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to print a single value from a map.

```
   var myMap = {
      0: {
        key: 754, 
        name: luke, 
        time: 1665537500000}, 
      1: {
        key: 436, 
        name: obi, 
        time: 1665532400000},
    }

print(myMap[1].value("name"); // something like that
```

output should be: obi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to achieve this way :

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> myMap = {
    0: {"key": 754, "name": "luke", "time": 1665537500000},
    1: {"key": 436, "name": "obi", "time": 1665532400000},
  };

  print(myMap[1]["name"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specify Map before "myMap", you should be able to use

```
print(myMap[1]["name"]);
```

[But your question seems duplicated from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963880/dart-how-to-access-second-dimension-in-multidimensional-map) so please check online before duplicating.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  var myMap = {
      0: {
        "key": 754, 
        "name": "luke", 
        "time": 1665537500000}, 
      1: {
        "key": 436, 
        "name": "obi", 
        "time": 1665532400000},
    };
  print(myMap[1]?['name']);
}
```

**Output**:
[image]